# How to process socket data in a Struts2 web application?

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, struts2

The are variations of this question on Stack Overflow; however, none seemed to answer my question.  Apologies if this question truly is a dup.

I have a Struts2 web application that needs to access data through a socket from a C++ application running in our data center.  I will send a command and get a clob of data back.

The buffered reader on the InputStream from the socket will be very active.  I do not want this process to block the other processes in my web app.  I always thought that it was "best practice" NOT to create multiple threads within a web application.  Is there an elegant way to process socket data in a Struts2 web application without creating multiple threads? Thx!

Comment: It's "best practice" to use threads when you need them (or the concurrency utilities in EE7, etc.)

Comment: The best practice is to open multiple sockets to underline application and one per each thread.